# Installing a progressive web app (PWA) on Chromebook

Tags: chromebook, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing a PWA that already works fine as such on Desktop and Android. On Android, it can be installed on the home screen and runs offline.

I would expect that this makes the app installable on Chromebook as well, allowing the app icon to be installed into the task bar, for example, without the need for a dedicated "Chrome App" (since I see non technical reason for that).

However, I can't find a way to *install* my app **manually** on my Chromebook (Chrome OS 54) - there does not seem to be any "install" command in the menu.

Is this simply not supported (why?) or does this require special settings in the manifest or something?

Answer (score 0):

I think the equivalent, for now, of installing a progressive web app on a chrome book, is to select More Tools from the "Customize and Control" button (three vertical dots lately) and select Add to Shelf.  Check the "Open as Window" option.

Answer (score -2):

Based on Google Support documentation[https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/2588006?hl=en], you should be able to install apps or extension in your browser window as buttons on the toolbar.

Try to install apps to your chromebook using steps below:

- Open the Chrome Web Store.
- In the left column, click Apps or Extensions.
- Browse or search for what you'd like to add.
- When you find an app or extension you'd like to add, click Add to Chrome.
- If you're adding an extension:
- Review the types of data that the extension will be able to access.
- Click **Install**.

You'll see your apps in your launcher, and your extensions in your browser window as buttons on the toolbar.

**Note**: You can't add apps or extensions if you're browsing as a guest.

Comment: But this will only find apps that have been added to the Web Store, right? What if I have already a PWM site open and just want to add that?

Comment: answer is unrelated to pwa